# Primefaces slider doesn't appear

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm trying to add a primefaces slider element, but it doesn't appear/show/display at all. Like, I put it in `<h:body>` (`<h:head>` also exists), inside the `<h:form>` :

`<h:inputHidden id="R"/>
<p:slider for="R" minValue="2" maxValue="5" step="1" id="Rslider"/>`

and have nothing in html in the place I put it (simply no tags).

Console logs this:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: this.jq.slider is not a function TypeError: this.jq.slider is not a function
    at c.init (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:33:471)
    at c.e.(anonymous function) [as init] (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:5:335)
    at new c (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:5:437)
    at Object.createWidget (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:1:4706)
    at Object.cw (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:1:4527)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/lab.xhtml:44:147)
    at l (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677)
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.jq.slider is not a function
    at c.init (components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:33)
    at c.e.(anonymous function) [as init] (http://localhost:8080/helloworld/javax.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:5:335)
    at new c (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:5)
    at Object.createWidget (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:1)
    at Object.cw (core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=3_3_0_130419&v=6.0:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (lab.xhtml:44)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Tried to download different versions and themes, but no result.

```
<p:inputText>
```

and `<p:spinner>` works ok.

Comment: Checked for more than one PF versions

Comment: Being deployed at the same time I mean... And checked it it was an issue in the 6.2 release (tried 6.3-SNAPSHOT e.g.)